# Magento 2 : How to generate Add to Cart URL

Tags: magento2

I am looping some specific products on the home page but unable to generate the ADD TO CART URL in magento 2

How to generate **ADD TO CART URL** when displaying products in **loop.**

Answer (score 9):

I know it's been a year since this has been touched on, but as I've just done what has been requested, I thought that I may post my solution to help others.

The other answers will work, but only for simple products, where no further input is required (e.g. selecting options). When using `getAddToCartUrl()`, Magento first checks if the products requires any options to be selected; if it does, then it will simply supply the URL to the product page instead.

To skip all of these checks and directly obtain the add to cart URL, then make use of the **Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart** helper instead. If you are within a .phtml file, then this can be utilised simply by calling `$this->helper`:

```
$cartHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');
```

From there, you can generate the add to cart URL via `getAddUrl()`, ensuring you pass the product object as the parameter:

```
echo $cartHelper->getAddUrl($product)
```

For it to fully work, you must have a hidden field for the form key as described in the other answers, and if the product in question has compulsory options to choose from (e.g. a configurable product), then make sure you include those fields as well, otherwise you will get redirected to the product page itself, with a message informing the user that options are required.

Comment: I like this suggestion, because using Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart can also be done in a Controller or a Model, not only in a Block or template. This should be the accepted answer IMO.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this solution. How do you define $product?

Answer (score 3):

The excellent solution is to use

```
$cartHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');
```

and after that

```
echo $cartHelper->getAddUrl($product);
```

this give add to cart URL every time 
(for a simple product, for a simple product with custom options etc)

Answer (score 2):

use following to generate add to cart URL in magento2:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$listBlock = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');

$addToCartUrl =  $listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($product);
```

Comment: It generates the URL but when i click on this link it takes me to the CART with not item. (You have no items in your shopping cart.)

Comment: Ye me too I shall look for soltion now

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: Object Manager shouldn't be used - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly

Comment: On list page this code redirects to product view page for configurable products and works for simple products.

Answer (score 2):

Add your button code into form with **form key**.. It will work

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$listBlock = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');

$addToCartUrl =  $listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($product);

<form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $addToCartUrl; ?>" method="post">
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
       <button type="submit"
               title="Add to Cart"
               class="action tocart primary">
               <span>Add to Cart</span>
        </button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Don't use object manager directly

Answer (score 0):

You can generate "add to cart" url by following code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$listBlock = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
$addToCartUrl =  $listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($_product);
```